# How to limit string field by characters in Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Documents looks like this:

```
[
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e41877df4cebbeaebec5146"),
   "title": "this is a title",
   "Paragraph" : "My Name is John Smith.I am learning MongoDB database"
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e4187d7f4cebbeaebec5147"),
   "title": "this is a title",
   "Paragraph" : "David Miller is a good student and learning Spring and Hibernate Framework."
}
]
```

I want to limit Paragraph field text to 6 characters like this:

```
[
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e41877df4cebbeaebec5146"),
   "title": "this is a title",
   "Paragraph" : "My Nam"
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e4187d7f4cebbeaebec5147"),
   "title": "this is a title",
   "Paragraph" : "David "
}
]
```

I tried this code but it's removing every other field:

```
{
        $project:         {
            Paragraph: { $substr: [ "$Paragraph", 0, 6] }
            }      
}
```

Comment: Use `$set` instead of `$project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
        $set:         {
            Paragraph: { $substr: [ "$Paragraph", 0, 6] }
            }      
}
```